# Xlwings python pandas dataframe groupby returning duplicate data

Tags: python, pandas, xlwings

I would like to group column 0 and sum column 1. I'm using a named range for 'x', which we will call x. The data it is looking at is as follows:

```
1207    1500
1222    1500
1211    1500
1218    1500
1208    1500
1204    1500
1216    1500
1215    1500
1212    1500
1205    1500
1213    1500
1221    1500
1209    1500
1214    1500
1202    1500
1203    1500
1206    1500
1210    1500
1217    1500
1220    -10950
1219    -12675
1217    500
```

The code below works fine if I select the exact size range, somewhere else, and use ctrl+shift+enter. It returns the exact same data.

```
@xw.arg('x', xw.Range)
@xw.ret(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=False)
def udf_groupby_range_x(x):
    res = x.options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=False).value
    return res
```

However, when I use the following code all of the cells of data change to 1500.

```
@xw.arg('x', xw.Range)
@xw.ret(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=False)
def udf_groupby_range_x(x):
    res = x.options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=False).value
    res = res.groupby(res.columns[0])[res.columns[1]].sum()
    return res
```

```
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
1500    1500
```

How do I get it to return this?

```
1207    1500
1222    1500
1211    1500
1218    1500
1208    1500
1204    1500
1216    1500
1215    1500
1212    1500
1205    1500
1213    1500
1221    1500
1209    1500
1214    1500
1202    1500
1203    1500
1206    1500
1210    1500
1217    2000 (was 1500)
1220    -10950
1219    -12675
1217    500 (gone)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, I’m just curious: What are you using xlwings for?

Comment: I'm a fixed income bond trader and I use Excel for some trading analysis. I'm moving away from VBA, now that I just learned about Python. I'm a total newbie but Python is allowing me to manipulate data within Python much more easily. Thhis question was related to the need to concatenate two named ranges in Excel, group them by the cusip, sum the quantities and then drop the duplicate cusips.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out all I needed was .reset_index(). I added in some more code, that I already had but took out to minimize confusion, and it now works. This will take a named range that has the data, and empty cells below the data, sum column 1 then group by column 0 and delete duplicates.

```
@xw.func
@xw.arg('x', xw.Range)
@xw.ret(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=False, expand='table')
def udf_groupby_range_x(x):
    res = x.options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=False).value
    res = res.groupby(res.columns[0])[res.columns[1]].sum().reset_index()
    res = res.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
    res.fillna("", inplace=True)

    return res
```